# How do I diagnose a MySQL query failure in a PHP page?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I am trying to create sitemap.xml file and get all brands from my  database. I have following code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>';
echo'<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';

include 'includes/modules/connections/db.php'; //database connection
$brands = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brands WHERE brand_status = 1"); //Select all brands
$row_brands = mysql_fetch_assoc($brands);

do { ?>
<url>
<?php
//Check when brand pages was last time updated 
$brand_update = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_history WHERE brand_id = ".$row_brands['brand_id']." ORDER BY uh_date DESC");
$row_brand_update = mysql_fetch_assoc($brand_update)
?>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/brand/<? echo $row_brands['brand_url']; ?>/</loc>
    <lastmod><?php echo $row_brand_update['uh_date']; ?></lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
<?php } while ($row_brands = mysql_fetch_assoc($brands)); ?> 
</urlset>
```

however I get below errors. I tried many changes but always come up with different error. Anyone sees a problem in above code that cause below error?

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<br/>
<b>Warning</b>
: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in
<b>
/hermes/bosoraweb060/b2763/ipg.example/sitemap-brands.php
</b>
on line
<b>8</b>
<br/>
<url>
<br/>
<b>Warning</b>
: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in
<b>
/hermes/bosoraweb060/b2763/ipg.example/sitemap-brands.php
</b>
on line
<b>15</b>
<br/>
<loc>http://www.example.com/brand//</loc>
<lastmod/>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
<br/>
<b>Warning</b>
: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in
<b>
/hermes/bosoraweb060/b2763/ipg.example/sitemap-brands.php
</b>
on line
<b>22</b>
<br/>
</urlset>
```

Thanks a lot got help!

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score -2):

SWITCH TO SOMETHING BESIDES mysql_ ! Keep using mysql and the intertoobz wil pwn ur w3bs1te, srsly. That being said, I will answer your question in the context you asked it.

Your first error message, when you untangle the HTML from it, says this:

> Warning  : mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in
>   /hermes/bosoraweb060/b2763/ipg.example/sitemap-brands.php on line 8

You can look at line 8 of your code and see that there's only one argument passed to that function.  That argument was produced by this line in your code:

```
 $brands = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brands WHERE brand_status = 1");
```

So, this thing `$brands` that you're trying to get back from mysql_query is no good (it's not a valid MySQL result resource).

What could be wrong? Your SELECT statement has failed.

That could be because your database doesn't contain a `brands` table, or because it does contain a `brands` table but that table has no `brand_status` column.

It also could be because you need to call mysql_select_db("database") before you run a query. Look at this:   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

You should probably adjust your code to include the following lines right after your call to mysql_query().  This will cause your program to show you the error messages from MySQL itself, not just the PHP, so you can figure out what's going wrong in your SELECT.

```
if (0 != mysql_errno()) { 
  echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(). "<br/>\n";
  exit ("MySQLfailure.<br/>\n");
}
```

You can put this right after every query, and leave it in your production code.

Comment: using mysql_* is considered harmful.